# Query to get repeated customers between start and end date

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am having a table with following attributes :

```
Date | Inv_Num | Cust_Name
```

Now, Given a start and end date I want all the Cust_Name that have multiple invoices with Date laying in the period?

Customer is not considered repeat if the difference between two invoice dates is  less than 30 days.

Example :

```
01/19/2013  201237  A
01/11/2013  201235  A
01/05/2013  201276  B
03/05/2013  201256  B
12/12/2000  201010  C
```

If here StartDate is say 01/01/2013 and EndDate is 06/06/2013 then here A is not repeated customer while B is repeated customer and C is not in range mentioned. How to handle this query please help. Main problem am facing is how to compare the records after grouping them according to the Cust_Name.

Comment: Note that dates in MySQL adhere to a specific format. Fix that, then get back to us.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below [Not Tested]

```
select a.cust_name
from invoice a join invoice b 
on a.cust_name = b.cust_name 
and a.`date` < b.`date`
where datediff(b.`date`, a.`date`) > 30
```

Comment: What about start and end date ?

Comment: There is no such column in your table. query will compare two different rows date per condition. Also, point what @strawberry mentioned and fix the date format.

Comment: Conceptually sound but not fully accurate.  OP said do not count if less than 30 days, so your test should be `>= 30`.

Comment: @Rahul Its just an example. The start and end date may vary and also the records of table

Comment: @python_slayer, query I posted is per the table schema you have provided in question. You should consider providing more info if you think posted table schema is not actual.

Comment: @Rahul Edited post. Please check

Comment: @python_slayer, Thanks for the edit but I am still bit confused. Can you edit your post and include the actual table schema.